# How can I ensure that all C functions and types are prefixed with 'std::' in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, std

Since most implementations directly include `<xxxxxx.h>` headers in `<cxxxxxx>` headers, C functions and types are introduced into both the global namespace and the `std` namespace, and thus the following code compiles fine with most compilers:

```
#include <cstdio>
// some other #includes

int main(){
    std::printf("Some string\n");
    // some code
    printf("Some other string\n"); // Forgotten!!!
    // some other code
    std::printf("Some other string\n");
    // some other code
}
```

However, the code is non-portable even though it compiles fine, since it is implementation-defined whether `::printf` exists. It is easy to forget the `std::` prefix, but hard to find out when the code is very long, for no hints or warnings are produced even with clang's `-Weverything`.

So, is there a convenient way to find this out?

Comment: Note that the problem is no different from having your system headers create any other non-standard identifier in the global namespace.  Easiest is probably to find a cross-compilation target where the headers don't expose extra names.

Comment: Workaround: if you declare `using std::printf;` the code will now be portable and conformant whichever way you write it. I tend to do this with identifiers that were in the standard library before `std::` and that will never be redefined in any other library, and `printf` certainly qualifies. Besides, I’ve written `printf` and `cout` for decades and it feels more natural.  It’s inadvisable to use it with classes like `string`, `vector`, `array` or `list` that have been reinvented thousands of times.

Comment: You can look through your implementation of the library to see if there is some `-D` flag to turn this behavior off, but the standard bowed to existing practice and explicitly allows implementations to do that. There is not, to my knowledge, any portable way to guarantee that no identifiers will be added to the global namespace. You can, however, `#include <stdio.h>` in C++ and be guaranteed to get the names in the global namespace.

Comment: It's the first time I hear that it's implementation defined if symbols from `<cxxxx>` headers are in global namespace... can you provide some source for that?